# too_many redirects_ OKTA authentication

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, okta, okta-api

I am getting OKTA login Screen but after entering credentials applications goes in an infinite loop to redirect url.

Login URL: http://localhost:9090/

redirect URL: http://localhost/9090/login

OKTA settings:
[image]

Error on browser:
[image]

Anyone face this issue earlier?

Technology  :springboot ,OKTA

Comment: Can you try clearing your cookies or using an incognito window?

Comment: Can you also please share your security configuration? It appears your "/login" page is also secured and it's redirecting to "/login" for you to log in.

Answer (score 4):

So after 2 days straight of trying to figure this out I found something. If you are using

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.okta.spring</groupId>
<artifactId>okta-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
<version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Then spring is by default listening for the okta code on http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/okta

So when I put in my custom redirect uri like all the tutorials say (/authorization-code/callback) okta was finding that as a secured page. EVEN when I put that same end point in application.properties okta.oauth2.redirect-uri.

I am still having some trouble figure out the auth but at least the non stop redirects have stopped and I am getting unauthorized.

Comment: I encountered the same issue. Finally, I just ended up setting the redirect-uri to what @Ryan has mentioned, both in the application.properties as well as okta client config dashboard and the auth worked.

Answer (score 0):

It's redirecting to login again. 
You need implement one rest api as  :-

```
@RestController
public class oktaTest{

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String welcome2User(Principal principal) {
        return "Hi "+principal.getName()+" Welcome to App";
    }

 }
```